# How to include custom artifact in distribution in gradle

Tags: gradle

I'd like to know how to include a custom build artifact in the distribution zip built with gradle in a *canonical* way. I've managed to do it by referring to the path of the artifact directly, but I'm guessing there's some better way to achieve this:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: tasks.classes) {
    classifier 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

tasks.distZip.shouldRunAfter tasks.sourcesJar
tasks.distTar.shouldRunAfter tasks.sourcesJar

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from { "${libsDir}/${project.name}-${version}-sources.jar" }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I refer to the name of my sources artifact based on its definition, or alternatively is there an even better way to include built artifacts in the distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be e.g.:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'distribution'

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: tasks.classes) {
    classifier 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

tasks.distZip.shouldRunAfter tasks.sourcesJar
tasks.distTar.shouldRunAfter tasks.sourcesJar

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from { tasks.sourcesJar.archivePath }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just refer to the jar task directly like so:

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from { sourcesJar }
        }
    }
}
```